# Need to deserialize my entities but they are on a dedicated API project

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I'm currently working on 2 projects:
 - #1 : The website, templates, etc. (on symfony)
 - #2 : On a separate project, my API (on Symfony with API Platform)

I make requests from the project #1 to that project #2 and get a json response, up to now it's just a normal behavior.

But here is the problem, how can I deserialize my response to an object on project #1 if I can't access my Entity file?

I searched many solution on Google but all of those solutions need a direct access to the entity file, but me I can't because they are on my API project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deserialize the results you get from an API into actual entity *instances*, **you simply won't be able to do it from the consuming side of the relationship if the classes themselves are not available**.

More often than not, you normalize should normlize the result into an array and deal with that, or if anything into a class that the web project know about.

Or, make the entity class definitions a shared component between the two projects.

How, exactly, would be different depending on how your code is organized. You could manage it wit git (submodule or subtree), or even a shared composer package both projects would depend on.

If you do either, and you have ORM and Api-Platform configured with annotations, I would move the configuration into separate files (e.g. XML mappings), so that you would only be sharing classes definitions, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!